# converting string to a special kind of variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to use strvalue instead of value in

```
  var date = (DateTime)value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

in the following code. actually I need to use a Persian date time picker and I need to convert my number to English  so I forced to convert value as a string to replace characters.

```
 public class DateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private static readonly CultureInfo arabic = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
    private static readonly CultureInfo latin = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

       var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        String strvalue = (String)value.ConvertTo(typeof(String), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        var latinDigits = latin.NumberFormat.NativeDigits;
        var arabicDigits = arabic.NumberFormat.NativeDigits;

        for (int i = 0; i < latinDigits.Length; i++)
        {
            strvalue = strvalue.Replace(arabicDigits[i], latinDigits[i]);
        }

        var date = (DateTime)value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);    
        date = PersianCulture.PersianToGregorianUS(date);
        return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem again?

Comment: @ if you noticed I said that I need to use strvalue instead of value. so I need a method to convert string as a value variable type. Also I put my code because I thought maybe there would be a better way than converting that someone might suggest.

Comment: have you looked into the `DateTimeFormatInfo` class? Also [How to Set PersianCalendar...](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32096/How-to-Set-PersianCalendar-to-CultureInfo). He talks about having to extend `DateTime` to make `PersianDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after googling much I find the way, maybe it could help someone

```
  ValueProviderResult value1 = new ValueProviderResult(strvalue,strvalue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

  var date = (DateTime)value1.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```